# What IC can perform such mixing?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I want to synchronize the rising edges of two signals.

Normally two wave forms are not sync as follows(yellow is unrelated to the question):

[image]

To put it simply I want to obtain the green waveform from the blue and the orange wave forms as follows:

[image]

Here is the zoomed view:

[image]

As you see above, what IC can mix the blue and orange waveforms as inputs and produce the green output waveform?

Comment: Do you have control over generation of the signals yourself? Because normally you would use the blue signal as a clock for your  brown signal and that would get rid of the problem. Or can you only apply delay lines to them?

Comment: Actually, reading your question again, you don't seem to be asking for edge alignment so much as using the brown signal as a gate for the blue signal. In that case you can just use flip flops with an AND gate. Although your diagram seems to indicate that if brown happens LATER then you want it to occur earlier to line up with blue, but that is non-causal.

Comment: Blue is coming from an uC continuously. Brown is controlled, it will be generated by the user SW.

Comment: If that is the case then, depending on how close you need the signals to be, have user SW only edge transition brown on a blue rising edge and run both signals through an AND gate.,

Comment: It is from this article its about long but maybe you can look at related section and have an idea: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9229119

Comment: They use Arduino for blue.

Comment: an AND gate ? possible with a D flip-flip if you need the green signals to be 'whole' pulses

Comment: @jp314 Have you seen the link I provided in the comment? Did I formulate the  question correct? So an and gate IC would do the job?

Comment: If you don't care that the occassional blue square pulse might be cut off a bit in the green signal then just an AND gate will work. If you want only full blue square pulses to appear in the green signal then you also need a flip-flop somewhere.

Comment: [Phase synchronization](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52981/synchronize-a-software-waveform-generator) is possible, but requires some effort.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for the comment. Only rising edges trigger(frame trigger and line trigger) in this system. Have you seen the paper in the link? So don't you think it wouldn't matter using just an AND gate? Waveform might not be exact occasionally but both systems(brown and green) will start triggering at the same time. Correct?

Comment: I saw the paper but I do not know if it matters or not. I would say the first and last green pulse would almost never be the same as blue.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop